# Sublime Text 2 : About Mark and BookMarks

Tags: sublimetext2

** Sublime Text 2 :Win 7  **

1. What's the difference between Edit -->Mark and  Goto -->BookMarks ?
2. Why does Edit -->Mark can only set one Mark in my Sublime Text ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`This helpful link`](https://robdodson.me/sublime-text-2-tips-and-shortcuts/)

> I find myself using Marks a few times a day to do large selections.
>   For instance if you have a big block of HTML it can be very tricky to
>   stay inside the proper scope if you’re trying to delete all the
>   contents of a very high level container. With Marks you can just put a
>   mark on the opening line of the container, hit cmd+shift+a to select
>   down to the bottom of the tag, and then hit cmd+K, cmd+a to select
>   everything back to your previous mark.